# Are there any solutions to this functional/differential equation involving an infinite series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, functional-equations, laurent-series

I'm am interested in how to find solutions related the equation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {\mathrm d^i}{\mathrm dx^i}(f) = f.$$

If $n$ goes to infinity it seems like I can use taylor series to help find solutions. What I am really interested in however is, is there a method for finding exact solutions to this equation for arbitrary $n$? Also, is there a maximum or minimum $n$ for which solutions exist? Are there any conditions I am forgetting? I have tried looking at different questions or researching on the internet but "differential equation as a series" in searches returns something else.

Comment: Did you mean to have $f$ on the right side? Because the $i=0$ term contributes $f$ on the left, so the ODE would reduce to a simple linear equation, $f'+f''+\cdots+f^{(n)}=0$.

Comment: Yes, this is my first time using latex. Did not notice that.

Answer (score 3):

This is an $n$th order linear ODE, and is solvable by considering the characteristic equation. Note that the equation can be simplified to
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f^{(i)} = 0,$$
a homogeneous equation which has a characteristic polynomial
$$\sum_{i=1}^n r^i = r\sum_{i=1}^n r^{i-1} = 0.$$
Clearly $r = 0$ is a root, as $r$ is a factor. The remaining polynomial, $\sum_{i=1}^n r^{i-1}$, is a cyclotomic polynomial. Note that
$$(r - 1)\sum_{i=1}^n r^{i-1} = r^n - 1,$$
so the roots of $\sum_{i=1}^n r^{i-1}$ are all the strictly complex $n$th roots of $1$, which we denote $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_{n-1}$. The most general solution to the ODE is therefore,
$$f(x) = C_0 + C_1e^{\omega_1 x} + \ldots + C_{n-1}e^{\omega_{n-1} x},$$
for arbitrary constants $C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_{n-1}$.

I didn't use Taylor series here, but I honestly think this is the most straightforward approach.

Comment: I made an error stating the question, I meant for the series to start at i=1 and overlooked that the original function canceled out. Does this still apply?

Comment: Once the $f$ terms cancel, you can substitute $g=f'$ and you essentially recover the same equation, but one degree less.

Comment: @JamesShelton In abstract, yes it does. You can still form a homogeneous linear ODE from this equation, whose characteristic polynomial is $-1 + r + r^2 + \ldots + r^n$. The problem is, the roots of this characteristic polynomial aren't so nice, and would probably not have radical expressions. The equation definitely still has a similar solution, but we won't have the elgenace of $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_{n-1}$ to rely on.

Comment: @JamesShelton The result will be$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n C_i e^{\alpha_i x},$$where $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are the roots of $-1 + r + r^2 + \ldots + r^n$. I don't think you'll get much more informative than that, for general $n$ (in particular, $n \ge 5$).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this stuff sooner. I got caught up trying to look at it a different way thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f^{(i)}(x)=f(x).$$
We let $f(x)=e^{rx}$ so that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}r^{i}=1\implies \frac{r(1-r^{n})}{1-r}-1=0\implies r^{n+1}-2r+1=0.$$
In the case $n\rightarrow\infty$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}r^{i}=1\implies \frac{r}{1-r}-1=0\implies r=\frac{1}{2},$$
so it looks like there is only one solution of the form $e^{rx}$ with $r=1/2$. Note that for finite $n$ there is always one solution with $x=1$.